# Monitring Aurora

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, aws-aurora

We are currently migrating from SQL server to RDS Aurora. I am using Redgate to monitor the SQL Server database.  My manager recommending New Relic for RDS Aurora, however, I don't feel Newrelic deep inside the queries and provide recommendations.

My question For RDS Aurora what are the top tools which can be used to monitor the database?

Answer (score 0):

Read the recommended link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Overview.LoggingAndMonitoring.html . Cloudwatch is pretty good option